# Creating MVC Application That Can Easily Integrate Into Existing Applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a custom MVC Forum application. But I'm starting to think that although it works great as is, I'm going to need to get it to work within other MVC apps (In fact I have actually been asked that already).

What is the best way with an MVC app to structure/develop to make it as easy as possible to integrate into an existing MVC application?

Areas? Develop within a sub folder from the start? Or is it just you have to work through and merge configs/controller clashes if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No need to Config or ... . you only need to create ability in your Logon Model and it's Controllers. A complete example is in Asp.net MVC 4 which Microsoft has added more libraries for authenticate from other sites/profiles. Also the model has changed a few in properties. see this technology or download MVC 4 framework to learn it. it's easy.